# Fixing file://(///) link download issues in every browser (in mediawiki)?

Tags: browser, download, mediawiki

At our office we use mediawiki as our intranet portal. Some of our departments like Sales, Support, etc use it to manage files on the network. They often link to Word/Excel documents with a file:// uri. The issue is everybody uses different browsers, ie explorer, Firefox, chrome. Often they cannot download files (link not working in certain browsers, browser security settings, etc). Is there a way to fix this for everybody without having to install additional software or change settings on each PC?

If possible I would like to keep linking to these local network files. I'd rather not upload them to google docs (extra work!) and use a share-link so it's just http.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the mediawiki way of posting links?

`[[LinkHere]]`

This might help with your issue, since MediaWiki chooses the way it is displayed.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Links

Sorry. Cannot comment yet. This is not an answer.